# Replace cast by function call in C++

Tags: c++, casting, refactoring

Any recommendations of a tool or method to refactor/replace casts such as:

```
(type*) data
```

into:

```
convert_to_type(data)
```

Things become trickier when `data` has higher priority operators, parenthesis or line breaks in it:

```
(type*) a(b)->
              c
```

should become `convert_to_type(a(b)->c)` not `convert_to_type(a)(b)->c` etc.

Comment: `static_cast<type*>(data)` or type conversion overloading!?

Comment: Also note that `(type*) data` is C-style cast. In most of situations, what you should use is `static_cast<type>(data)` or `dynamic_cast<type>(data)` while dealing with polymorphic types.

Comment: @MM., he is asking how to do it automatically

Comment: you certainly can't do this reliably with regular expressions, because  C++ isn't regular. The only thing which comes to mind therefore is create a smart tool based on clang.

Comment: if "c" is a class you could overload `operator type*()`, so that this operator will be called when you cast to type*

Comment: You certainly have to parse some C++.  I'm not sure that it requires something as complete as clang, but it could.  After all, you _don't_ want to change things like `int function(type*);`.

Comment: Ummmm... what about regex?

Comment: See [Parsing C++ in Python with Clang](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/) for ideas how to create your own tools.

Comment: I know what the various casts do, I'm trying to replace pre-existing C-style casts with a function call.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a tool that's able to properly parse and replace these automatically.

The best option I'm aware of is to use g++ with `-Wold-style-cast` which will then helpfully warn you for all such C-style casts, allowing you to disposition them properly by analyzing the code in question. This will obviously take more time than a tool but it also give you the opportunity to review and prevent a tool from doing an incorrect conversion.

Comment: -Wold-style-cast would blow thousands of false negatives, not an option for me unfortunately. I want to replace one specific cast.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you will want a semantically aware C++ parser. There are not so much tools.

Actually, the only one I can think of is Clang. Using [its AST Matchers](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchers.html), you can write a program to retrieve the AST nodes that correspond to a C-style cast and then issue a textual replacement. Because Clang's AST is fully semantic aware, you will have access to both the expression undergoing conversion, its type *and* the type it was converted to.

There are examples in the tools or extra section, for example you could check out the [Cpp11Migrate](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/clang-tools-extra/trunk/cpp11-migrate/Cpp11Migrate.cpp) tool for both matching *and* replacing.

Note: you will want to get acquainted with [Clang's AST](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html) if you go down this road.

Answer (score 1):

> Any recommendations of a tool or method to refactor/replace casts such as:

There shouldn't be any. This problem is tricky enough, that when the C++ casts (static_cast, cost_cast, etc) were created, one of their explicit goals was "they should be easy to find in code, using automated tools.

In some cases, a tool would need full parsing before determining if a pair of parenthesis is used for an arithmetic operation (parenthesis used for operator priority), a cast, or something else.

You are better off changing them one by one (you will introduce less errors that way).

If your code base is big, you may also benefit from writing your own tool for this purpose (gcc has warnings for this so they should be easy to find).

Comment: "You are better off changing them one by one (you will introduce less errors that way)." I'm not as confident as you are hahaha :)

Answer (score 0):

Kinda think this will blow up in your face at some point, but:

```
template<typename T> T myFunc()
{
    // do stuff
    return (T) retVal;
}
```

Comment: He is not asking how to define such function, he is asking how to replace all casts automatically.