# C++ mixing pointers to different char types

Tags: c++, casting, warnings

I am writing a program in C++ that takes an ACT (Adobe Color Table) file and converts it to a plain-text readable JASC-PAL file. I want to read the binary data from the ACT file and store it in memory to use. I wrote the following code to do that and it builds using BCC55. The problem is I get a build warning: "Warning W8079 : Mixing pointers to different 'char' types in function read_file()".

```
unsigned char * memblock;

bool read_file()
{
    int filesize;
    ifstream act ("test.act", ios::binary|ios::ate);
    if (act.is_open())
    {
        filesize = act.tellg();
        act.seekg(0);
        memblock = new unsigned char [filesize];
        act.read(memblock, filesize);
        act.close();
        cout << "Color Table loaded to memory." << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failed to open file." << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Looking this warning up at the Embarcadero documentation wiki it seems to be because I am passing a unsigned char pointer to a function expecting a regular char pointer. It says this is technically incorrect but usually harmless. My question is if this is, strictly speaking, incorrect then how do I go about doing this without causing the W8079 warning at build time? Should I even bother with this since the warning is harmless and my code works as expected?

Comment: Usually you should never ignore warnings from the Compiler... Are you releasing your Memory somewhere? This is even worse...

Comment: Why are you using `unsigned char` for `memblock` ?

Comment: There's a certain amount of ick when different APIs come together - the standard C I/O type is `char`, but the natural type for a byte store array is `unsigned char`... happily, the types are entirely layout compatible, but you may have to put a cast in at some point.

Comment: Yes I release the memory at the end of the main() function with delete[]. Sorry I didn't include that bit since I wasn't really in question about that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a cast. In this case I would just use a simple C cast.

```
act.read((char*)memblock, filesize);
```

but you could use reinterpret_cast as well

```
act.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(memblock), filesize);
```

but this makes it seem a bigger deal than it is. As the documentation says, this is harmless.

Comment: Thanks, I guess in this case the pointer type didn't matter since it's 1 byte either way. The reason I used the unsigned char was since the data I'm reading is to be interpreted as numbers and it was overflowing to negative values as a regular char.

Comment: Please never recommend C style casts in C++ code: they introduce points in code that are brittle, cause undefined behavior if our of sync with the data type), and are difficult to be found by tools (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408658/replace-cast-by-function-call-in-c). Basically, even if they are correct when you add them in code, they will have to be managed explicitly when you extend/maintain the code, but are hard to find in the code base.

Comment: For this code I can't think of any maintenance task where using a C style cast is likely to lead to future problems. I wouldn't have recommended it otherwise.